# Error in joomla and wamp after formated pc

Tags: joomla, wamp

i tried to search, but couldn't find anything.

Here is the problem, i've just formated my pc, reinstalled wamp and i want to put my site back to work on localhost but i'm having an error with the database communication.

I don't know if i'm forgetting something (clearly i'm forgetting something), but i uploaded the database joomla was using before i formated the pc and copy all the files on the www folder in wamp.

What the hell i'm doing wrong? Do i need to reinstall joomla?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Did you create the MySQL user that Joomla is configured to use?

Comment: Yes, the user and password are correct, the administrator page seems to work fine and all the posts and config i previously put there are right, the error is:
"Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\wamp\www\perfilo\plugins\content\jw_allvideos\jw_allvideos.php on line 42"
and it repeats for all the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you're previous WAMP server was running PHP 5.3 and you're now running PHP 5.4

In you're **php.ini** file, change the following line:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

to this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

This won't display the error, but it **will** log them

Comment: Well, that worked! Thank you. I downloaded the last version of Wamp server, and i didn't see the version of PHP. Does this wil bring any problem? should i download an older version?

Comment: In the future PHP 5.3 will be deprecated, so it's up to you if you want to start moving forward now or at a later date :) It's not mandatory as at a guess, the majority of servers still run PHP 5.3

Comment: Well, if ti's not happening any problem, i will move forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The error in your comment is the result of PHP reporting strict errors.

Joomla contains some coding issues, some more subtle than others and those trigger `Strict` and `Notice` messages.

You can handle this by telling the PHP engine to hide those messages by editing the following directive in your `php.ini` file :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will ask you too if this wil bring any problem? should i download an older version?

Comment: Definitely not. This version still supports this syntax. Hopefully Joomla should fix those issues by then time it is deprecated.